# Why can't I call the sum() twice?

Tags: pandas

I have this line of code:

```py
feat_table.at(i, 'pastHC')=(ht_stats[ht_stats["AwayTeam"] == ht].sum().HC + ht_stats[ht_stats["HomeTeam"] == ht].sum().HC)/k
```

However, when I run the cell on Jupyter, it gives me the error:

> cannot assign to function call

and it points to the second sum() function in the line of code.

Comment: The error pointer is wrong; the actual error is that expression of the form `function(args) = expression` are forbidden in Python. You probably want to use `.loc` instead of `.at`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `at`, you can't assign values with `at`, try using `loc`:

```
feat_table.loc[i, 'pastHC'] = (ht_stats[ht_stats["AwayTeam"] == ht].sum().HC + ht_stats[ht_stats["HomeTeam"] == ht].sum().HC) / k
```